# How to mass delete some lines of htmls in a directory

Tags: html, ddos

I think someone here can help me out of the trouble I'm facing.

I got my sites DDOSed and all the html files in my site were added 7 lines of codes at the end of the files. I downloaded all the contaminated files and would like to remove all those bad codes. But the task was overwhelmed. There are 400+ htmls.

So I would ask those gurus, is there any method that I can bulk delete the last 7 lines? I tried notepad++ and other apps but failed to find a better way.

PS. the HTMLS spread in different directory.

Comment: First, you need to fix the underlying security hole.

Comment: Use regex or juste simple replace in notepad++ or coda , and replace all lines in a folder

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people seem to be using PowerShell for tasks like this these days.

Test this before you run it, but I think this is what you're looking for:

```
gci c:/USE_REAL_FOLDER_NAME_HERE/ | % {
    $path = $_
    $file = gc $_
    $file[0..($file.length-7)] | % {$_.trimstart()} | out-file $path
}
```